# PHP how to have the first match in an array without stopping the loop

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP I have this array:

```
 array
(
    [seriale] => 000000000000000000
    [stato] => 
    [byname] => Array
        (
            [35] => EV Pack
            [4] => Software AUTO
            [20] => Software TRUCK
            [23] => Software EV
            [6] => Tecnical Smart
            [7] => SGW
            [18] => CarSET PRO
        )
    [integra] => Array
        (
            [4] => 24
            [20] => 12
            [6] => 12
        )
    [action] => modifica
)
```

And this loop

```
foreach ($_POST['integra'] as $key => $value) {
    if (str_contains($_POST['byname'][$key], 'Software AUTO')) {
       $durata = $value;
       echo "---------------------".$durata;
    } elseif (str_contains($_POST['byname'][$key], 'Software')) {
      .....
    }
    $prodlist .= $_POST['byname'][$key]."\r\n";
  }
```

in the second if I need to get only first match "Software" without stopping the loop.

Note that there are 3 "software" in the array.

thank you so much

sorry I can't format an array correctly!

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `isset` as the condition like this, so that `$foo` will be set only once.

```
.....
} elseif (str_contains($_POST['byname'][$key], 'Software')) {
  if(!isset($foo))
    $foo = $value;
}
.....
```

You need to ensure that `$value` cannot be null, otherwise this method won't work, but you only need to add an additional variable.

```
$value_is_set = false;
.....
} elseif (str_contains($_POST['byname'][$key], 'Software')) {
  if(!$value_is_set) {
    $foo = $value;
    $value_is_set = true;
  }
}
.....
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works perfectly.
Thank you